# Moving email attachment from Inbound email to Case

Tags: integration, case, email2case

I was going through Sample Questions on Salesforce Integration Architecture Exam Guide.
I came across this Sample question.

Universal Containers implemented email-to-case to allow customers to email their
support requests. They found that cases were getting created correctly, but the email
attachments weren't attached directly to the cases. Instead, they were attached to the
emails under the Open activities related list.

Which two options should be considered to make sure the attachments get attached
directly to the cases?

Choose two answers

A. Choose the option Save attachments under Cases in email-to-case setup options.

B. Write a trigger on the Case to copy/move attachments from email activity to case.

C. Use the Email handler service to extract attachments and create under Cases.

D. Set up web-to-case to automatically create attachments under Cases.

The answers given are B and C.

I am okay with the C option, But B option is confusing me.

B option says writing a Trigger on Case, Now my question is First Case is created and then the EmailMessage is created. Without creating case we cannot attach a WHatId/relatedTo on email message, so basically the trigger should be on Email message.

Am I missing something? Anyone can help me here?